# A generalization of relative interior?

Tags: gn.general-topology, convex-analysis

In an infinite-dimension space, the relative interior of a non-empty convex set may be empty. I was wondering whether there is a concept (as a generalization of relative interior) with the following properties: for any non-empty convex set,

1. Its "concept" is non-empty.
2. Whenever the relative interior of this set is non-empty, its "concept" is the same as the relative interior.

This was posted on [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4735301/a-generalization-of-relative-interior).